# Recursively remove all occurrences of an item in a linked list

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

```
public static Node deleteAll(Node front, String target){
    if (front == null){ return null;}
    if (front.data.equals(target)){
        return deleteAll(front.next,target);
    }
    front.next=deleteAll(front.next,target);
    return front;
}
```

I'm trying to walk through this solution, but it is confusing me. Why doesn't it always result as null since at the end front will equal null.

Comment: it returns the result from first function call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When thinking about such problems it is a good idea to get a pen and paper and draw some stuff and think about it on a high level

For example
...............
Input
List: [3]-[2]-[5]-null
Target: 2
................

First call  => Result

`deleteAll(N[3], 2) => [3]`
but next is now `deleteAll(N[2], 2)`
`List = [3]-deleteAll(N[2], 2)`

Second call

`deleteAll(N[2], 2) => deleteAll(N[5], 2)`
next node now skips the 2
`List = [3]-deleteAll(N[5], 2)`

Third call

`deleteAll(N[5], 2) => [5]`
but next is now deleteAll(null, 2)
`List = [3]-[5]-deleteAll(null, 2)`

Lat call returns null

List ends up clean with no 2s
`List = [3]-[5]-null`

Answer (score 0):

You have three cases:

1. The original `front` node is null, so you return null.
2. The original `front` node holds `target`, so you discard `front` and return the result of the recursive call on the linked node.
3. The original `front` node does not hold `target`, so you perform the recursive call on the linked node and return `front`.

In number 1 you return null and in number 3 you return non-null. In number 2 you basically go again, and so return null or the next node. And so on.

This means it's possible to return null. But it's also possible to return non-null.